# Extending objects within Ember.js Controller breaks

Tags: ember.js

I am working with the object model in Ember.js at the moment. I really like it but there's one thing that confuses me.

This works (http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jepazo/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output):

```
App.Car = Ember.Object.extend({   
      color: 'red',   
      brand: "Tesla",   
      desciption: function(){
           return this.get('color') + this.get('brand');   
      }.property('color','brand') 
})


App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({   
   zl: [App.Car.create(), App.Car.create({brand: 'BMW'})] 
})
```

But I can't declare it on the controller (http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jepazo/2/edit?html,css,js,console,output):

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  car: Ember.Object.extend({
      color: 'red',
      brand: "Tesla",
      desciption: function(){
         return this.get('color') + this.get('brand');
      }.property('color','brand')
  }),
  zl: [this.get('car').create(), this.get('car').create({brand: 'BMW'})]
)};
```

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: The code in your question looks correct, the code in your fiddle is missing a `});`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because "this" in your array declaration is the Window object.

If you turn zl into a computedProperty that returns the array it will work.

Something like:

```
zl: function() {
      return [this.get('car').create(), this.get('car').create({ brand: 'BMW'})];
    }.property()
```

Here is a jsbin illustrating the issue:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/fudiruduxa/1/edit?html,css,js,output